# How to toggle airplane mode in iOS with Appium Java client

Tags: appium-ios, appium-desktop

I was able to swipe up the "quick settings" in iOS with a swipe touch action, but viewing the UI with Appium Desktop I was not able to see the xml of the settings panel. Does the settings panel have any xml in Appium? How can I click on the the airplane mode button without seeing the xml? Do I have to estimate the correct coordinate? Won't this coordinate change from device to device? [Here](https://discuss.appium.io/t/change-mobile-state-to-offline-mode-airplane-mode-on-android-and-ios/5094/20) is the best attempt I could find by someone on google.

**edit**

Is it possible that Apple framework does [not allow](https://discuss.appium.io/t/switch-app-to-browser-and-back-to-app/987/2) automation of more than one app at a time? Is this why I can't see the xml of the setting panel? It's like a separate app? Do I have to re-initialize the driver during run time to change the phone airplane mode?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I can get the location of a view behind the airplane mode button and guesstimate the coordinates for the click event, and change the coordinate based on the device uuid in a case switch statement. Don't see a better alternative, unless someone has a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle Airplane mode in ios by navigating to the settings menu of the iOS.
To do that you need to switch from your native app to iOS settings app bundle.
You can find the link below with sample code snippet for [toggle Airplane mode in iOS](https://dzone.com/articles/internet-offline-scenario-automation-on-android-and-iOS-mobile-App)